# T-SQL Current and Previous Status

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, mssql-jdbc

I have a Database where I am looking to get current room numbers and previous room numbers.

The data looks like this.
Table X

```
Name, room_number, Start_Date, End_Date, status
Bob, A1, 2015-04-03, null, transfer
Bob, B5, 2013-04-15, 2015-04-03, somestatus
Bob, B7, 2011-04-15, 2013-04-15, someotherstatus
Smith, A2, 2015-04-03, null, transfer
Smith, B4, 2013-10-15, 2015-04-03, someotherstatus
Smith, B8, 2011-04-15, 2013-10-15, somestatus
```

What I want to bring back is the below.

Bob, A1, 2015-04-03, null, transfer                     Current Room 
Bob, B5, 2013-04-15, 2015-04-03                Previous room 
Smith, A2, 2015-04-03, null, transfer                    Current Room 
Smith, B4, 2013-10-15, 2015-04-03              Previous room

Please let me know if this is clear enough.

What I currently have is

```
Select Name, room_number, Start_Date, End_Date, status
from TableX
where start_date = today
and status = transfer
```

which gives me all of the people rooms. Not sure how to get previous room numbers because the status outside of transfer doesnt mean anything. The commonality is that end date is not null if it is their current room

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW RoomChange
AS
WITH CTE
AS
(

    SELECT  Name,
            room_number,
            [Start_Date],
            [end_date],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY [Start_date]) room_order
    FROM TableX
)


SELECT  A.name,
        A.[Start_Date],
        A.room_number,
        B.[Start_Date] prev_room_start,
        B.room_number AS prev_room
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B
ON  A.room_order = B.room_order + 1
    AND A.Name = B.name
WHERE A.[end_date] IS NULL --only grab latest room
GO


SELECT *
FROM RoomChange
```

Results:

```
name  Start_Date room_number prev_room_start prev_room
----- ---------- ----------- --------------- ---------
Bob   2015-04-03 A1          2013-04-15      B5
Smith 2015-04-03 A2          2013-10-15      B4
```

Comment: I working on it now, odd for some reason WHERE [end_date] IS NULL is stating that it is an invalid column which is kinda strange

Comment: It was because I forgot to add it in my list of columns in my CTE. If you want the other columns, add them to the CTE. Remember the CTE aliased "A" holds current room and "B" holds previous room information.

Comment: Are you able to create the CTE as a view?

Comment: Create View RoomChange as
;WITH CTE